# Syntax error from missing semi colon

Tags: javascript

Any ideas why I keep getting this error code:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop condition.
```

I already tried adding a semi-colon at the end.
Here is my code:

```
        var numberOfQuestions = 3;

    for(i = 0; i <=3 numberOfQuestions; numberOfQuestions--) {
        if (numberOfQuestions == 3) {
            var adjective = prompt('Please type an adjective ' + '3 questions left');
        }
        if (numberOfQuestions == 2) {
            var verb = prompt('Please type a verb ' + '2 questions left');
        }
        if (numberOfQuestions == 1) {
            var noun = prompt('Please type a noun ' + '1 question left');
        }
    };
        alert('All done. Ready for the message?');
        document.write("There was once a " + adjective + " programmer who wanted to use Javascript to " + verb + " the " + noun);
```

Comment: `i <=3 numberOfQuestions` – what’s that supposed to be?

Comment: it's for the for loop to iterate over the variable? am I missing something here?

Comment: More often than not, a syntax error doesn't necessarily point to the actual error that was made - rather to the point in the code where the interpreter failed to understand the syntax. The errors usually occur just before the line complaining about a syntax error.

Comment: You mean `for (var i = numberOfQuestions; i=>0; i--) {` and then `if (i == 3) {` or just `var adjective = prompt('Please type an adjective ' + '3 questions left');  var verb = prompt('Please type a verb ' + '2 questions left');
        var noun = prompt('Please type a noun ' + '1 question left');`

Comment: Freecodecamp.com is a nice way to start learning JS, you should start learning the basics before copy-pasting code and try to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
i <=3 numberOfQuestions
```

by

```
i <=numberOfQuestions ; //
```

in your for-loop middle condition

Comment: Surely he should rather replace it with `i < numberOfQuestions; i++`? `numberOfQuestions` will never reduce in value and `i` will never increase so right now it'd be an infinite loop. Either that or `for (var i = numberOfQuestions; i >= 0; i--)`.

Comment: I know, I just mentioned what was causing syntax error for him. Kudos to you for taking out time and analyzed his code threadbare :)

Answer (score 2):

There's several things here. First of all, as others have pointed out your loop has an invalid value here:

```
for(i = 0; i <=3 numberOfQuestions; numberOfQuestions--) {
               ^^^
```

Let's assume you want to start from `numberOfQuestions` and count down. In that case you need to set `i` to `numberOfQuestions` and then reduce the value of `i` in your loop:

```
for (var i = numberOfQuestions; i >= 1; i--) {
```

This means "set `i` to `numberOfQuestions`. While `i` is greater than or equal to `1` run the loop. After the loop is executed reduce `i` with 1 (`i--`)".

There's also no reason to use

```
if (a === 1) {
}
if (a === 2) {
}
```

If `a` is 1 then it will never be `2` so there's no reason to check all of the values. Instead you should use `else if`.

Thirdly, you should be aware of variable hoisting meaning that you might *think* that you declare your variables inside of your loop, but you're really not. This will confuse you later, so just declare them first. The end result would be code looking like this:

```
var numberOfQuestions = 3;
var i, adjective, verb, noun;

for (i = numberOfQuestions; i >= 1; i--) {
    if (i === 3) {
        adjective = prompt('Please type an adjective ' + '3 questions left');
    } else if (i === 2) {
        verb = prompt('Please type a verb ' + '2 questions left');
    } else if (i === 1) {
        noun = prompt('Please type a noun ' + '1 question left');
    }
};

alert('All done. Ready for the message?');
document.write("There was once a " + adjective + " programmer who wanted to use Javascript to " + verb + " the " + noun);
```

If you rather just want to change `numberOfQuestions` I'd recommend a `while` loop instead:

```
var numberOfQuestions = 3;
var adjective, verb, noun;

while (numberOfQuestions > 0) {
    if (numberOfQuestions === 3) {
        adjective = prompt('Please type an adjective ' + '3 questions left');
    } else if (numberOfQuestions === 2) {
        verb = prompt('Please type a verb ' + '2 questions left');
    } else if (numberOfQuestions === 1) {
        noun = prompt('Please type a noun ' + '1 question left');
    }

    numberOfQuestions--;
};
```

**That said** - why are you even using a loop? You need all the values, so just use `prompt` directly:

```
var adjective = prompt('Please type an adjective - 3 questions left');
var verb = prompt('Please type a verb - 2 questions left');
var noun = prompt('Please type a noun - 1 question left');

alert('All done. Ready for the message?');
document.write("There was once a " + adjective + " programmer who wanted to use Javascript to " + verb + " the " + noun);
```

Comment: `+numberOfQuestions+' question'+(numberOfQuestions==1?"":"s")+' left');`

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong in assuming the OP is looking for speed (given the decreasing iterator and for loop ), isn't the while slower ?

Comment: @Pogrindis speed? Using Prompt? No way. Each iteration is blocking using the prompt

Comment: @mplungjan `1 questions left`. No need to overcomplicate it. Sure you could set the prompt question and use `prompt(question + ' ' + numberOfQuestions + ' question' + (numberOfQuestions != 1 ? 's' : '') + ' left')` but it's still overcomplicating it for OP. Regarding performance, Pogrindis, I'm very certain that it'd be the exact same, seeing as it should do exactly the same behind the stage. It would also be microoptimization without reasoning.

Comment: haha. Porgrindis is microoptimizing and I am adding feature creep

Comment: @mplungjan While we're at it we might as well use an array of questions and use `pop` or `shift` to empty it to make sure that it'll require less work in the future ;-) I mean, really - there's no reason to even use a loop here as we require every single value. We might as well set it indidivually.

Comment: Best start to the working week all year! ^^

Comment: I mean, gramatically we should also check for a/an in the final message. Bloat it!

Comment: thanks for all the help guys, I made a few revisions of my own using an array. Here's my code: http://hastebin.com/emicogerav.coffee. I'm fairly new to programming and I am experimenting with stuff to learn how to manipulate data, so bear with me haha. anyway thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @defc0de You're still using `if, if, if` instead of `if, elseif, elseif` and there's absolutely no reason to use an array that contains `3, 2, 1` when you can just set `for (var x = 3; x >= 1; x--)`. Like I said though - there's no reason to even using a loop.

Comment: @defc0de That's completely fine - just letting you know. Hopefully you learned something :-)

Comment: yeah man thanks for all your help!

Comment: @h2ooooooo - I already suggested the loopless version here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282226/syntax-error-from-missing-semi-colon/36282460?noredirect=1#comment60190471_36282226

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 1; i <= numberOfQuestions; i++) {
    if (i == 3) {
        var adjective = prompt('Please type an adjective ' + '3 questions left');
    }
    if (i == 2) {
        var verb = prompt('Please type a verb ' + '2 questions left');
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        var noun = prompt('Please type a noun ' + '1 question left');
    }
};
```

try this instead of your for loop

Comment: This will say "1 question left" then "2 questions left" then "3 questions left" - doesn't make much sense. Also, it makes no sense to use `if, if, if` since if `i` is 3 then it definitely isn't 2 or 1.

Comment: actually this is supposed to be a counter of the questions left everytime an answer is entered int he prompt. so if the if statement doesn't make sense, what do you reckon to replace it with?

Comment: i was just fixing the for loop, i figured he could switch around the messages as needed (you can also use the i variable for the amount of questions left).

but @defc0de has already written a great answer, the only reason for a loop would be if you don't want to write the '3 questions left' part yourself.

in which case you should use the loop variable instead of handwriting the number